# How to add REST channel to Spring Webflow Application?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, rest, spring-webflow

I've downloaded **Spring Webflow** sources and I wanted to add REST channel (displaying the image from database) to the **jsf-booking** sample. This channel was working without problem in my **Spring-MVC** sample application.

However, I have problem with mapping, because on the given address the JSF handler is responding with error message that the display.xhtml file does not exist (and the REST listener should handle that request).

This is how I registered the handler:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/image")
public class ImageChannelImpl implements ImageChannel {

    @RequestMapping(value="/display.png", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void display(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
(...)
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();     
        log.debug("display finished");
    }
```

}

I've copied the handler mapping;

```
<bean

    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean id="byteArrayHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
```

The DispatcherServlet is listening on /spring/* requests:

```
<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all /spring requests to the Dispatcher Servlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, I have expected, that the image will be available on the address /spring/image/display.png, but the REST handler is not taking that request, neither it handles /image/display.png .

So, what must be changed in that configuration so that the REST channel can be registered? I was trying to google any sample or documentation, how to configure both Spring WebFlow and Spring MVC channels, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should define 'default handler' for your FlowHandlerMapping:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
    <!--If no flow match, map path to a view to render; e.g. the "/intro" path would map to the view named "intro" --> 
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="requestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" id="requestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

You can replace RequestMappingHandlerMapping with AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter depending on your Spring MVC version (RequestMappingHandlerMapping is the preferred way in last SMVC releases)